# Trouble Controlling and Changing Navigation BarBackgroundColor in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have been trying to change the background color of the Navigation Bar in Xamarin Forms. I have a MainPage.xaml which uses the following code in the App.xaml.cs file. This WORKS...

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
        {
           BarBackgroundColor = Color.AliceBlue, // Sets color of Navigation Top Bar
           BarTextColor = Color.White // Sets the text color of the Navigation Top Bar
        };
    }
```

The problem I have is that I start with a Splash page which displays a Lottie animation for 5 seconds, and then it navigates to the MainPage. When the MainPage appears, the Navigation Bar is always just white. I navigate to that page from my Splash.xml page with the following code in the Splash.xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class Splash : ContentPage
{
    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new MainPage()));
    }
}
```

I have tried placing the following in my App.xaml file but it doesn't have any effect:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="AliceBlue"/>
        </Style>

       </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Any ideas on what I am missing in order to declare and control the Navigation BarBackgroundColor in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm working with your code, trying to change a bright color to test

Answer (score 0):

In the first case it is working as expected. In this line:

```
await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new MainPage()));
```

you are creating a new `NavigationPage` so your previous code is irrelevant to it, if you want the same effect you need to set the color again.

Considering the second solution, I would expect it to work, so probably either you haven't tested it properly or you have some more code that overrides the behavior.

Comment: I should say that when I start the app from the Splash.xaml page which then redirects to the MainPage, I remove the code in the first part above and replace it with: MainPage = new Splash(); so there is nothing defining a navigation bar color except for what appears in my App.xaml file shown above.

Comment: @DanUnderhill if your question was how to make it work, I think my first answer is sufficient and you should accept it. If you wanted to ask two questions like why either code doesn’t work, those are two questions.

Comment: I was just trying to clarify my question was all.